# Making a Unified address search bar in ios 5?

Tags: ios, browser, address-bar

Help making a Unified address bar in ios 5 for a Browser App? So here is my address bar.

```
-(IBAction)url:(id)sender {
    NSString *query = [urlBar.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
    NSURL *urlQuery = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", query]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlQuery];
    [webPage loadRequest:request];
}
```

Couldn't I add an "else" reference to say if it is not an address then append the google search tag? If so how? And would you know how to use Bing instead of google?

```
-(IBAction)googleSearch:(id)sender {
    NSString *query = [googleSearch.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
    NSURL *urlQuery = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=&q=%@", query]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlQuery];
    [webPage loadRequest:request];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some tips to help you:

- use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` instead of your "+" replacement.
- you should check if http:// is not a prefix to the URL string before adding it
- you should implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol to identify when an error occurs when loading an invalid URL
- then as a fallback launch your Google search (now you can replace " " by "+")... or Bing, whatever and up to you!

Your code should looks something as follow:

```
...
webView.delegate = self; // Should appear in your code somewhere
...

-(IBAction)performSearch {
    if ([searchBar.text hasPrefix:@"http://"]) {
        ... // Make NSURL from NSString using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: among other things
        [webView loadRequest:...]
    } else if ([self isProbablyURL:searchBar.text]) {
        ... // Make NSURL from NSString appending http:// and using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: among other things
        [webView loadRequest:...]
    } else {
        [self performGoogleSearchWithText:searchBar.text]
    }
}

- (BOOL)isProbablyURL:(NSString *)text {
    ... // do something smart and return YES or NO
}

- (void)performGoogleSearchWithText:(NSString *)text {
    ... // Make a google request from text and mark it as not being "fallbackable" on a google search as it is already a Google Search
    [webView loadRequest:...]
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    ... // Notify user
    if (was not already a Google Search) {
        [self performGoogleSearchWithText:searchBar.text]
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response. My included code is working for 2 separate text fields just like in safari. I was wondering how to link them in to one. Maybe that was explained in the response but I have no idea how to use it. I don't just want someone to write it out for me but I'm very new to this and don't understand much yet. More help, please.

Comment: The behavior you've described is the one you can get by implementing my tips. The algo would be if (text from text field starts with http://) { go to the address } else ( append http:// to the content of the text field and launch the request ; if (request ok) { fini } else { go to google with the content of the text field }

Comment: So their text would be in the form of "*.*" that adds the http:// if the text is "*" or "* * *" then it sends to the google search. Is it that simple? I say "simple" even though I still wouldn't know how to write it.

Comment: This page removed the asterisks from my quotation marks. What mean to say is, text "something.something" go to that url if it's "something something" search with google.

Comment: i've updated to make my answer clearer. About the "do something smart", it will require your engineering skills. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not smart. I don't see how to tell it to add http:// and go to url and when to pass it to google search.

Comment: I got cut off...   Are you suggesting adding a search button along with a go button? Go should look at the text and if it looks like a url it goes to the url if it's just word or series of words the it performs a google search. Although, I would rather it be a bing search but that's another problem...

Comment: I'm afraid what you ask are very basic iOS programming skills so i recommend you to read the Apple documentation to learn more about NSString and UIWebView. I can't help more than what I already did here.